# Javascript function not accepting JSP created String

Tags: javascript, string, jsp

I'm using JSPs to create dynamic web pages...

At the beginning of one of my forms, I have some javascript that needs to run to initialize the page with given attributes.

I'm creating a Java String in the JSP <% %> blocks that I want to pass to the initializePage javascript function.

Here's the code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
<%String algorithmXMLPath = request.getContextPath() + "/" + PePw.PATH_ALGORITHM_XMLS;
String initParms = "'" + algorithmXMLPath + "'," +
                   " '" + Utilities.getString(reqBean.getMachineType()) + "'," +
                   " '" + Utilities.getString(reqBean.getModel()) + "'," +
                   " '" + Utilities.getString(reqBean.getReasonCode()) + "'";%>
initializePage(<%=initParms%>);
});
</script>
```

This results in a source code of:

```
initializePage('/PePasswords/data/algorithmXMLs/', '', '', '');
```

When I run this, I get an error in the FF error console "Unterminated String literal" and it points to the end of the initializePage call... When I click the link in the error console, it actually points to the line with });

Not sure what i'm doing wrong here...

Comment: Would they happen to be backslashes rather than slashes?

Comment: @user1428716 Why do you suggest that? The resulting page (in the browser) would have nothing where the scriplet is. Right?

Comment: Just for giggles, I moved the scriplet part out of the <script> tags... moved the declaration of that String to the beginning of the JSP with other things i'm setting... Exactly the same result. Except now the link in the error console points to the closing </script> tag

Answer (score 1):

Looks like one of the variables had a hidden new line "\n" being passed into the JSP call...

I replaced

```
Utilities.getString(reqBean.getReasonCode())
```

with

```
Utilities.getString(reqBean.getReasonCode()).replace("\n", "").trim()
```